# Jolt merge array values from objects in one array

Tags: object, merge, jolt

I have the following Json array:

```
[ {
  "name" : [ "roger", "roger" ],
  "state" : [ "primary", "quality" ],
  "value" : [ 1, 2 ]
}, {
  "name" : [ "david", "david" ],
  "state" : [ "primary", "quality" ],
  "value" : [ 4, 5 ]
} ]
```

and I want to have the following Json object result using Jolt

```
{
  "name" : [ "roger", "roger" , "david", "david" ],
  "state" : [ "primary", "quality" ,"primary", "quality" ],
  "value" : [ 1, 2 , 4, 5]
}
```

please someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply **shift** transformation twice such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&.&1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "0": {
          "*": "&2[]"
        },
        "1": {
          "*": "&2[]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where determine the keys(`&`) and respective indexes(`&1`->`0` and `1`) by prepending ampersand of keys such as `"&.&1"` in the first step, then dissipate each respective values through use of `"*": "&2[]"` in which `&2` represents going two levels up in order to traverse two curly braces in order to reach the root key to target the each values of the arrays.